# Finding out if a varchar contains a percent sign, in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Can't find an answer to this...

How can I select rows where a certain column (varchar) contains a percent sign (%), in MySQL ?

Comment: for SQLSERVER will be `WHERE col LIKE '%[%]%'`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
where col like '%|%%' escape '|'
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know you could specify an arbitrary escape character

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM <YOUR_TABLE>
WHERE <YOUR_COLUMN> LIKE '%\%%'
```

Comment: So, to clarify a bit for others, this example is searching for "<wildcard>%<wildcard>". The percent sign literal, in this case, is escaped as `\%`.

Answer (score 8):

I beleive if I'm not mistaken the MySql escape is the "\" character.

You could do a select like:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn LIKE '%\%%'
```

Comment: I twinge when I see \ in mysql code, since it is normally paired with php and the possibilities for errors are endless

Comment: liking out a column that may or may not contain the '%' is just bad mojo imo... but I have no idea what the OP requires so I'll keep my oppinions to myself on that particular cat in the bag.  W/o knowing the circumstances or language the OP is using can't really add to much more... but yes... php + the escape character in mysql can be bad.

Comment: It's not to be used from PHP. It's just a "maintenance query" that I want to run to check how many of my URLs contain escaped characters. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from table_name
WHERE [column_name] like '%['+char(37)+']%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use less commonly used special characters as your escape character, you can do this:

```
WHERE col LIKE CONCAT('%', CHAR(0), '%%') ESCAPE CHAR(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE locate('%', col) > 0
```

In MSSQL CharIndex should be faster than LIKE. I haven't tested comparison between locate and LIKE in MySQL.