# Search for a multiple percent signs

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find '%%' string in content.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn LIKE '%\%\%%'
```

But it returns also the rows, where **only one** percent sign found.

How to find only the rows, where two percent signs exists?

Thanks.

Comment: try something like Like '%' + char(49) + '%'

Comment: Seems like this issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489666/finding-out-if-a-varchar-contains-a-percent-sign-in-mysql?rq=1). Suggestion is `where col like '%|%%' escape '|'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are indeed only looking for literal `%` and don't need the wildcards, this would be made simpler using [`LOCATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate), where the `%` will be parsed as literals requiring no escaping.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE LOCATE('%%', myColumn) > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But i need to use like structure, because i use this query for all kind of searches.

Comment: @Syom To be clear, using `LOCATE()` will work similarly to a `LIKE` query, unless the `LIKE` clause contained internal wildcards as in `LIKE %something%else%`

Answer (score 2):

you can also use **[`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)** for this,

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE str REGEXP '%%'
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c46f/2)